# I wiped my microSD with DBAN and now I can't use it

Tags: partitioning, micro-sd-card, dban

few days ago I have wiped my microSD card by Darik's Boot and Nuke with PRNG Stream method. Now I formatted my SD to fat32 file system but my Android phone doesn't recognize it, and so does my PC. I created an GPT Partition table but it can't help. Please help me fix this, thanks a lot to any helpers. Sorry for bad English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a MBR format - I suspect most non 'pc' devices arn't set up for gpt, and there's no real advantage to it.

A good idea would be to use the [official SD card association formatter](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/) - since it'd have a sane set of defaults, and is actually designed to do this.

Comment: Could you please show me how to do that by GParted or something like that? (I mean do a MBR format)

Comment: That tool would probably handle the whole process. Otherwise, you could just use fdisk I think.